# Bounding $\|X_1/(X_1+X_2) - Y_1/(Y_1+Y_2)\|_p$ by the closeness of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics

This question is inspired by the answer to [this other question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456058/upper-bound-on-difference-of-correlated-ratios/456067), but I have tried to make it self-contained and to zoom in on the counter-example from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456067/514711).

Suppose $\{(X_n, Y_n)\}_{n=1}^2$ are two i.i.d. joint probability distributions (that is, $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are not i.i.d., but $(X_1, Y_1)$ is i.i.d. with regards to $(X_2, Y_2)$), with $0 < X_n, Y_n \le 1$. I am interested in the quantity
$$ \left\|\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2} - \frac{Y_1}{Y_1 + Y_2}\right\|_p. $$
My intuition is that, as $X_n$ and $Y_n$ "get really close together" (i.e., $\|X - Y\|_p$ becomes smaller), this quantity should be upper-bounded by $C\|X-Y\|_p$ for some $C$ that depends on $X$. The previous question I asked on this forum, and which I referenced earlier, was concerned with a more general version of this quantity, but I studied this question's version in detail when trying to prove the more general one. I was unable to prove such a bound.

The reason was that such a bound does not exist; [the answer I mentioned before](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456067/514711) gives a clever explanation of this based on a counter-example where $X_1,X_2$ are independent random variables each uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,1)$; $Y_1=h+(1-h)X_1$ and $Y_2=h+(1-h)X_2$, where $h\in(0,1)$. However, this reply made me wonder whether such a bound did exist for a lower power: can one prove that
$$ \left\|\frac{X_1}{X_1 + X_2} - \frac{Y_1}{Y_1 + Y_2}\right\|_p \le C\|X-Y\|_p^\alpha \qquad \text{for some $0<\alpha<1$} $$
with $C$ a constant that depends on $X$? I investigated this question some more, but have not yet found any bound I can prove. I do have the following considerations, which seemingly conflict:

- In the counter-example, I do not see why the fraction $\frac1h$ could not be replaced by $\frac1{h^\alpha}$ with $0<\alpha<1$, which would invalidate the possibility of finding a bound such as the one I am looking for. I might, however, have missed a subtlety in the counter-example. EDIT: I now see why one cannot use $\frac1{h^\alpha}$ in that counter-example; disregard this bullet.
- On the other hand, I did some numerical tests that seemed to show very clean $\sim h$ (and thus $\sim \|X-Y\|_p$) convergence of the quantity of interest. I looked at its $(p=2)$-norm, which I estimated by using $10^6$ samples. The plot below suggests a very clean convergence to 0 at a rate $\sim h$.

[image]

I would be appreciative of any ideas as to whether this bound using $\|X-Y\|_p^\alpha$ can be attained. If no, how else could I quantify mathematically the intuitive and numerical fact that my quantity goes to zero as $\|X-Y\|_p$ does so?

Thank you for reading through the post! I look forward to hearing your ideas, especially given the detailed and helpful answer I received in response to my last question.

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you state clearly the inequality that you want to prove or disprove?

Comment: I edited the question, I hope it's clearer now. Basically, you proved that a bound using $\|X-Y\|_p$ cannot exist, but I am wondering whether one exists with $\|X-Y\|_p^\alpha$. It seems that your counter-example can be adapted to show that such a bound does not exist for any $0<\alpha<1$, but I'm finding that difficult to square with my numerical experiments, which seem to show $\sim\|X-Y\|_p$ convergence of my quantity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such a bound does not exist.

This is shown by the following modification of the [previous example](https://mathoverflow.net/a/456067/36721):

Suppose that $X_1,X_2$ are independent random variables each with the pdf given by the formula
\begin{equation*}
    f(x)=\frac c{x\ln^2 x}\,1(0<x<1/2) \tag{1}\label{1} 
\end{equation*}
for $c:=1/\int_0^{1/2}\frac{dx}{x\ln^2 x}$;
$Y_1=h+(1-h)X_1$ and $Y_2=h+(1-h)X_2$, where $h\in(0,1/2)$.

Then $0\le Y_1-X_1\le h$ and hence
\begin{equation*}
    \|X_1-Y_1\|_r\le h  
\end{equation*}
for all real $r>0$.

On the other hand, writing $A\gg B$ if $B=O(A)$, we get
\begin{equation*}
    \Big|\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}-\frac{Y_1}{Y_1+Y_2}\Big|
    =\frac{h|X_1-X_2|}{(X_1+X_2)(2h+(1-h)(X_1+X_2))}
    \gg1
\end{equation*}
on the event $\{X_2\le X_1/2\le h/2\}$. So,
\begin{equation*}
    \Big\|\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}-\frac{Y_1}{Y_1+Y_2}\Big\|_p^p
    \gg\int_0^h dx_1\,f(x_1)
    \int_0^{x_1/2} dx_2\,f(x_2)\asymp\frac1{\ln^2 h}. 
\end{equation*}
So, letting $h\downarrow0$, we see that the inequality
\begin{equation*}
    \Big\|\frac{X_1}{X_1+X_2}-\frac{Y_1}{Y_1+Y_2}\Big\|_p\le C\|X_1-Y_1\|_r^\alpha
\end{equation*}
cannot hold for any real $C$ (even if $C$ depends on the distribution of $X_1$), any real $p>0$, any real $r>0$, any real $\alpha>0$, and all $h\in(0,1/2)$. $\quad\Box$

---

The OP asked in a [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456103/bounding-x-1-x-1x-2-y-1-y-1y-2-p-by-the-closeness-of-x-and-y/456119#comment1181281_456119) if the answer would change if it is additionally assumed that  $X_1=\exp(-U)$ and $Y_1=\exp(-V)$ for random variables $U\ge0$ and $V\ge0$ of which all finite moments exist.

Then the answer still remains negative, with \eqref{1} replaced by
\begin{equation*}
    f(x)=\frac{1}{2 x}\,\exp\Big(-\sqrt{\ln\frac1x}\,\Big)\,1(0<x<1),  
\end{equation*}
keeping essentially the same reasoning.

Comment: Again a clever counter-example! This gave me a lot of insight into the problem, so thanks for that. In my application, we have $X=\exp(-U)$ and $Y=\exp(-V)$ for random variables $U\ge0$ and $V\ge0$ of which all finite moments exist. In your example, $X_1 = \exp(-c/Z_1)$ with $Z_1$ uniformly random on $(0, 1)$, which means that it falls outside my application. Of course, you could not have known this :-) Do you think it is worth me repeating the question with this restriction, or will a bound still not exist in that setting?

Comment: @ArBo : With this additional condition, I don't have an answer at the moment. So, I think it may be worth posting the modified question separately. In general, it may make sense to disclose at once all your cards that you would eventually disclose.

Comment: I'll post a modified question in a few hours! I should definitely have mentioned this condition, but before seeing this counter-example, I didn't realise it was relevant (as it always goes, of course). I'll be careful to include all constraints in the modification.

Comment: @ArBo : Such an additional condition does not help, alas. See the added response to your comments.

Comment: How do you come up with these... Thanks!